# Filter JDK Bug System by JavaFX

Tags: javafx, java

Is there a way (filter settings, etc) to see only JavaFX related bugs in the [JDK Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK)?

Also, the Reporter names seem to be gone. Now I'm "J. Duke", I guess like everyone else that doesn't have an acount there. So how do I find the bugs I reported?

Comment: Well.. we all are clones of "J. Duke" now..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about getting support for JDK bug-tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample JavaFX issue query string:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JDK%20AND%20component%20%3D%20javafx

Created by:

1. Browse to: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK
2. Click on `All Issues`
3. Click on `+ More Criteria`
4. Check `Component`
5. Click Component drop-down.
6. Check `JavaFX`

Comment: Thanks, so it's a component now. I just tried, this url seems to work directly: [JavaFX Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK/component/11900).

Answer (score 0):

Reporter also works in advanced (jql) mode (reporter = 'your name'). Find one of your issues by other means and then copy your name as it is displayed there. Worked for me.